# How can I set up multiple ColdFusion test sites on my local machine using IIS?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am currently setting up a development machine at my company and I would like to be able to set up a few local sites on this one machine for testing. In order to do so, I am running the following software:

1. ColdFusion Server 10 (Developer's Edition)
2. IIS

Everything is installed and I am able to run the default site (from localhost) but I can't figure out, nor can I find how I can set up other sites on this system. I have the files for each site on the local machine. Ideally, I would like to be able to call up each site using a subdomain, such as (http://site1.domain.com, http://site2.domain.com, http://site3.domain.com) where each one points to a separate file base on the local machine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're only browsing the sites locally, you can add entries to your hosts file. Then set up separate websites in IIS and specify the name of each domain specified in your hosts file as the IIS domain name.

Comment: Can I use IP addresses other than the default 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Sure. You can enter any IP address and any domain name as a pair. But if you're wanting to use a non-local IP address, then it sounds like you're wanting to test from a remote machine. If that's the case, everyone testing against the site must set up their on hosts file with the same IP/domain entries. Otherwise, you'll need to get your IT folks to add a wildcard DNS record that points to your test machine so that you can do subdomains on demand for any sites you want to set up, which would eliminate the need for hosts file entries.

Comment: I don't want to do anything remotely. I just want to develop and test on my local machine. My assumption is that if I use the same IP address and port for all of the sites that it will conflict. Is this not the case?

Comment: It won't conflict if the domains are different. You must have a unique combination of IP, PORT, and DOMAIN. You can have all your sites on 127.0.0.1:80, as long they each have their own unique domain.

Comment: Ahh! So it looks like my assumption was my problem. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the sites in IIS for each site, pointing to its respective web root. Then run the web server configuration tool to hook up the connectors for the sites.

You can find that under {ColdFusion root}/cfusion/runtime/bin/wsconfig.exe (on windows - not sure of the file extension on non-windows machines)

From there you can run the connector for each individual site or you can set it to run the connector for every site.

Comment: I had originally set it up for all IIS sites and after setting up the same virtual directories in my first site as what is there for the default site it appears to be working correctly.